# Store database password in program with no key in source code

Tags: security, encryption

I am writing a simple database application. The program should get database information (host,name,user,pass) and store them for next uses. So I need to encrypt them and store encrypted information in a file. On the other hand I don't want to put any passwords in program code. My question is how should I store key for encryption algorithm in program? (the key used for encrypt database information)

Comment: are you able to use a trusted connection?

Comment: @Daniel No. How is that related to storing password?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469267/ok-so-ive-encrypted-my-data-now-where-do-i-hide-the-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the key in an external file and make sure the file permissions allow only the application user to access it.

Comment: If you change the file permissions in Windows (I think from Vista) I think that would have a similar effect.... no?

Comment: I have no experience with security in windows. I think it's better to embed password into executable, probably using resources... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Machine ID such as a CPU sn, but you won't e able to move te file to another system.